# Research on the link of QE and increased economic activity

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy

Im looking for good literature of quantitative easing and the effects on economic actitivty.

- from a modelling perspective
- Any empirical research?

What I am thinking of, is how much of an effect does QE actually have for citizens?